# Simple search in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, search

I want people to be able to search from a title field and a short description field (max 150 characters), so no real full-text search. Mainly they search for keywords, like "salsa" or "club", but I also want them to be able to search for "salsa" and match words like "salsaclub", so at least some form of partial matching.

Would the new Search API be useful for this kind of search, or would I be better off putting all keywords, including possible partial matches, in a list and filter on this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to put all the keywords and partial matches (some sort of support for stemming etc) might work if you limit yourself to small numbers of query terms (ie 1 or 2) anything more complex will become costly. If you want anything more than a one or two terms I would look at the alternatives.

You haven't said if your using python or java, go php.  If python have a look at Whoosh for appengine https://github.com/tallstreet/Whoosh-AppEngine  or go with the Search API.